# top nav bar blocking my content, how to i fix it?

Tags: html, css

I have some issues, when I put some paragraph or anything like that... the navbar covered up. can someone help me what actually wrong with my code? thanks...
this is my html Code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>SA-MR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SAMRnavbar.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav>
          <div class="wrap">
          <div class="title">
                 <div class="kotakpersegi">
                    <a href="">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="180" height="50">
                    </a>
                 </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tblmenubox">
            <div class="togel tblmenu">
    
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fiture</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(".togel.tblmenu").click(function () {
          $(".menu").toggleClass("sh");
          });
        </script>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    
    
    </body>
    </html>

this my CSS code.

    body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #eff2f7;
}

a   {   

    left: -50;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px
}

a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background: #1e77b0;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul li a {
    padding: 0 50px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.menu li:hover{
    background-color: #009cff;
}

.wrap{
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tblmenubox {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.tblmenu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #1e77b0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.tblmenubox{
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}


.kotakpersegi {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #009cff;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
    -o- transform: skew(30deg);
    transform: skew(30deg)
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px){

    .kotakpersegi {
        width: 150%;

    }

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    left: 25%;
}

  .menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .tblmenubox{
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .menu.sh {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background: #1e77b0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #eff2f7;
    background: #009cff;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

I have been try to add some padding top to 65px like another but, i doesn't work. i hope i can found the solution, thanks guys...

Comment: Show us what's in `css/SAMRnavbar.css`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `position: fixed`, just like `position: absolute`, pulls the element out of the document flow, so the area it takes up no longer occupies any space.  You can see this in the example below, where the first paragraph is occluded by the `<nav />`:

```js
$(".togel.tblmenu").click(function() {
  $(".menu").toggleClass("sh");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #eff2f7;
}

a {
  left: -50;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px
}

a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  right: 0;
  background: #1e77b0;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul li a {
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #009cff;
}

.wrap {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tblmenubox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.tblmenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #1e77b0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.tblmenubox {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.kotakpersegi {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #009cff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
  -o- transform: skew(30deg);
  transform: skew(30deg)
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .kotakpersegi {
    width: 150%;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    left: 25%;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .tblmenubox {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .menu.sh {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background: #1e77b0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    color: #eff2f7;
    background: #009cff;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SA-MR</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SAMRnavbar.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="kotakpersegi">
          <a href="">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="180" height="50">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tblmenubox">
        <div class="togel tblmenu">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fiture</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navbar -->

  <div>
    <p>ONE: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
    <p>TWO: Mary's violet eyes made John stay up nights proposing.</p>
    <p>THREE: Roy G Biv</p>
    <p>FOUR: Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If the `position: fixed` approach is your desired approach, you could put a wrapper around all content that follows it, and give it a `margin-top` that is the same height of the `<nav />` (*if* this is a known, fixed quantity):

```js
$(".togel.tblmenu").click(function() {
  $(".menu").toggleClass("sh");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #eff2f7;
}

a {
  left: -50;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px
}

a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  right: 0;
  background: #1e77b0;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul li a {
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #009cff;
}

.wrap {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tblmenubox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.tblmenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #1e77b0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.tblmenubox {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.kotakpersegi {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #009cff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
  -o- transform: skew(30deg);
  transform: skew(30deg)
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}

.content-wrapper { /* added a top margin */
  margin-top: 50px; /* We know this is the height because it is applied specifically in CSS */
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .kotakpersegi {
    width: 150%;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    left: 25%;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .tblmenubox {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .menu.sh {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background: #1e77b0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    color: #eff2f7;
    background: #009cff;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SA-MR</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SAMRnavbar.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="kotakpersegi">
          <a href="">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="180" height="50">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tblmenubox">
        <div class="togel tblmenu">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fiture</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navbar -->

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <p>ONE: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
    <p>TWO: Mary's violet eyes made John stay up nights proposing.</p>
    <p>THREE: Roy G Biv</p>
    <p>FOUR: Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally</p>
    <p>FIVE</p>
    <p>SIX</p>
    <p>SEVEN</p>
    <p>EIGHT</p>
    <p>NINE</p>
    <p>TEN</p>
    <p>ELEVEN</p>
    <p>TWELVE</p>
    <p>FOURTEEN (FOR LUCK)</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the content still scrolls fine behind the `<nav />`.  There are other ways to achieve this, using `flex` or `grid`, but for the `position: fixed` approach this will work.